# classic asp sql connection string error

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I'm getting an error related to my connection string and couldn't find a solution.

My connection string is

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB; Driver={SQL Server}; Server=ServerName; 
      Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxxx
```

I am using this connection string on classic asp page for updating aspx page using ajax call. But it keeps giving me "Unspecified Error" and "Invalid connection string attribute" errors. But the thing is the error message keeps changing :S

By the way, I have sql server 2012.

Do you have any idea??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

In this link you have all formats of string connection for Sql Server 2012

Link : http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

You can try with this format :

```
Provider=....;Data Provider=....;Data Source=myServerAddress;
Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```